# Auto imports are always absolute from the src folder in a ReactJS project in WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, webstorm, tsconfig

- I recently added TypeScript support to a Webpack ReactJS project.
- Furthermore, I added some import alias abilities to be able to make some imports absolute from the `src` folder to avoid long relative imports.

Ever since the TS configuration, I have this issue where imports are **always** absolute from the source folder.

Here is an example:

I have a folder with components A.tsx and B.tsx. When I auto-import component B into component A, I expect the import to be as followed:

```
import B from './B';
```

The problem that I have is that WebStorm auto imports it as followed:

```
import B from 'app/components/subfolder/B';
```

Screenshots for my tsconfig.json and webpack configurations:

[image: tsconfig.json]

[image: webpack configuration]

I looked at this resource link and still was not able to change the auto-import back to relative. [Configuring the Style of Imports in JavaScript and TypeScript](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2020/07/configuring-the-style-of-imports-in-javascript-and-typescript/)

How can I change the auto-import back to its default behavior?

When the project is run with VS Code I don't have this issue as I can explicitly specify the Import Module Specifier to be the "shortest".

Comment: please share a screenshot of **Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Imports** page

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Code, menu File → Preferences → Settings → User Settings,

```
"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative"
```

Comment: The question is about WebStorm, OP has explicitly stated that VS Code works fine.